# JPA Update changes not reflecting in the Database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to update a record in an Oracle database, using this code:

```
@Transactional
public void updateLedgerAccountDetails(LedgerAccount ledgerAccount) {

    try {
        GrlMaeItemDet grlMaeItemDetUpdate = grlMaeItemDetRepository.findByPk(ledgerAccount.getGrlItemSistCcosto().getCodSistem(),
                ledgerAccount.getGrlItemSistCcosto().getGrlCodItem(),
                ledgerAccount.getGrlItemSistCcosto().getCodEmpres(),
                ledgerAccount.getGrlItemSistCcosto().getNumPeriodo());
        grlMaeItemDetUpdate.setCodImpsto(ledgerAccount.getGrlMaeItemDet().getCodImpsto());

    } catch (Exception e){
        log.error("An error has occured: ", e);
    }
}
```

And with this repository

```
@Repository
public class LedgerAccountRepository {

public interface GrlMaeItemDetRepository extends JpaRepository<GrlMaeItemDet, PkGrlMaeItemDet> {
    @Query(value = AppConfiguration.MAE_ITEM_DET_QUERY, nativeQuery = true)
    GrlMaeItemDet findByPk(@Param("codSistem") String codSistem,
                           @Param("grlCodItem") String grlCodItem,
                           @Param("codEmpres") String codEmpres,
                           @Param("numPeriodo") BigInteger numPeriodo);

  }

}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working correctly, even when I'm already validating that the entry exists in the Database performing a findBy... that I've created, and even though Hibernate logs this:

```
Hibernate: update grl_mae_item_det set vige=?,fec_transc=?,hra_transc=?, cod_impsto=? where cod_empres=? and cod_sistem=? and grl_cod_item=? and num_periodo=?
```

The problem is as follows: I can't see the corresponding data being updated in the table (Using DBeaver), it basically stays the same, and when I run the program again and constantly fetch the entity, I can see it with the updated data in the terminal but not on the table, so it's like I'm seeing the same entry with two different sets of data, one on the code-side and another on the database-side (already confirmed that it's the same record).

I also tried running a manual script directly on the table and it seemed to work just fine, and not to mention that I have two other tables with the same exact code implementation as this one, and they update without an issue.

Edit: problem seemed to be related to the record I was using for testing as it seemed it wasn't updatable but I still wasn't getting errors, exceptions or warnings. As soon as I tried to update another record it worked. Leaving post up for future reference in case someone ever crosses the same scenario. Cheers.

Comment: Check the basics. Make sure you are connecting to the database you think you are.  Are you seeing any exceptions in the logs?  Create a test for this piece of code an isolate it from the rest of the env and try it there.

Comment: @Deadron I checked everything, database, table, attribute names, data types, absolutely everything and somehow I managed to 'fix' it? I can't really call it like that but the problem was for one singular record in the database that I was not able to update (no idea why, I'll have to ask the DB Admin), as soon as I tried a different entry, everything was updated without an issue, so that's strange.

Answer (score 0):

Save the updated data by using .save(). Add before catch block.
grlMaeItemDetRepository.save(grlMaeItemDetUpdate);